# where data get stored in sas by using stored process. using local server(work space) option

Tags: sas

I am using stored process for running bunch of queries and in that  i am creating tables.Code runs perfectly but where the table getting stored,i am not getting it?Since in log it shows no errors. Similarly i used  proc univariate, result's are displaying  but where that result getting stored?I am using using local work space library to store.

Comment: It would be better if you show the code because some procedures behave different to lets say a standard data step.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, your results are stored in work library. If you want to know where it is, you can see the path by running this code:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(work));
```

Keep in mind that work library reference is temporary and only relevant to your current session. Also, all datasets are temporary and they get wiped at the end of your SAS session.

For  proc univariate, you have to specify OUT= option and point where you want your summary statistics to be saved. If the report that you are after, use ODS destinations to save it to a permanent location.

Regards,
Vasilij

Answer (score 2):

To find the path being used by a libname (in this case the `work` libname), use this code:

```
%put %sysfunc(pathname(work));
```

For any output, it depends on your system setup, how SAS is started, etc...  Your output does not necessarily go to the same folder as your work libname uses.

I would use this code in windows:

```
filename x pipe 'echo %cd%';  * WINDOWS COMMAND TO RETURN CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY;

data _null_;
  infile x;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

In *nix, change the filename statement to:

```
filename x pipe 'pwd';  * UNIX/LINUX COMMAND TO RETURN CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY;
```

Or, as Vasilij suggested, use the OUT= option of the ODS statement.